# Scala + gradle + repositories flatDir{} is giving xsbti/CompileFailed error

Tags: scala, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

```
**gradle build:** is throwing  xsbti/CompileFailed error
```

Scala + gradle + flatDir as repository throwing xsbti complation failed error.
Please see the attached image
   [Scala Gradle Compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVvZZ.jpg)

```
**build.gradle**
```

My build gradle file is attached as below
    [Build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60tzI.jpg)

```
**Note: with MavenCentral repository its working fine. Only for flatDir as repository its not working**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**when flatDir is used as repository to compile scala + gradle 
add below code in gradle dependencies**

```
zinc 'com.typesafe.zinc:zinc:x.x.x'
zinc 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:x.x.x'
zinc 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:x.x.x'
zinc 'com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-interface:x.x.x'
zinc 'com.typesafe.sbt:incremental-compiler:x.x.x'
```

**EDIT** - corrected group name for incremental-compiler

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; When using `flatDir` your build is missing transitive dependencies

A `flatDir` repository is not like a maven or ivy repository. It doesn't support meta-data (eg transitive dependencies). If you want to store jars in a local folder, I suggest using the [maven repository directory layout](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final) and configuring in gradle as

```
repositories {
   maven {
      url uri('path/to/repo') 
   } 
}
```

With this format you can store poms beside the jars (including group, artifact, version and transitive dependency info). See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bmuschko/e4e04abca105c397145e) for a gradle task which can download the artifacts (jars and poms) from a [Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) to a local directory

See [flatDir documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:flat_dir_resolver)

> Note that this type of repository does not support any meta-data formats like Ivy XML or Maven POM files. Instead, Gradle will dynamically generate a module descriptor (without any dependency information) based on the presence of artifacts

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will try this.